# Meteor.loginWithPassword causes a page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a login form and the page keeps refreshing causing me all kinds of trouble.

I've tried this a few different ways. First is with a form making sure to `preventDefault` and return false.

```
<form id="login-form" class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="login-username" placeholder="Username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
  <input type="password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-outlined submit-button">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

And then for the event (in coffee script):

```
Template.login.rendered = ->
  console.log("rendering")
  Session.set("error", null)

Template.login.events
  'submit #login-form' : (e, t) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(e)

    # retrieve the input field values
    username = t.find('#login-username').value
    password = t.find('#login-password').value

    # Trim and validate
    username = _.str.trim username

    # login
    Meteor.loginWithPassword username, password,
      (err) ->
        if err
          Session.set("error", err.reason)
          console.log(err.reason)
        else
          console.log("home")
          Router.go("home")

    console.log("false")
    return false
```

If I return false before calling Meteor.loginWithPassword, everything works as expected. So i thought maybe its an issue with for submission. So I tried it without a form:

```
<input type="text" id="login-username" placeholder="Username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
<input type="password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
<button class="btn btn-block btn-outlined submit-button" id='login'>Sign In</button>
```

And then in coffee script:

```
Template.login.rendered = ->
  console.log("rendering")
  Session.set("error", null)

Template.login.events
  'click #login' : (e, t) ->
    console.log(e)

    # retrieve the input field values
    username = t.find('#login-username').value
    password = t.find('#login-password').value

    # Trim and validate
    username = _.str.trim username

    # login
    Meteor.loginWithPassword username, password,
      (err) ->
        if err
          Session.set("error", err.reason)
          console.log(err.reason)
        else
          console.log("home")
          Router.go("home")

    console.log("false")
    return false
```

Same exact problem! The page re-renders and I don't know why.

EDIT:

And here's the console log I get:

```
rendering login.coffee:2
jQuery.Event {originalEvent: Event, type: "submit", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1405971457745, jQuery111008379733411129564: true…} login.coffee:8
false login.coffee:27
User not found login.coffee:22
rendering
```

Also, this is all happening in the 'login' route

EDIT2: Maybe it has to do with onBeforeAction call. Is it reactive perhaps? I think Meteor.loggingIn is true even if the login is unsuccessful.

```
mustLogin = ->
  console.log "must login"
  unless Meteor.user()
    unless Meteor.loggingIn()
      console.log "go to login"
      @redirect('login')
      return true
  return false

alreadyLoggedIn = ->
  console.log "already logged in?"
  if Meteor.user() or Meteor.loggingIn()
    console.log "go to home"
    @redirect('home')
    return true
  return false


# Specify the url routes
Router.map ->
  @route 'home', 
    path: '/'
    onBeforeAction: mustLogin

  @route 'login', 
    onBeforeAction: alreadyLoggedIn
```

Comment: Hey, what did you do to prevent the refresh?

Comment: e.preventDefualt() inside a form submit. Default is old school, PHP style form submit (and a refresh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out with this little test:

```
Router.map ->
  @route 'home', 
    path: '/'
    onBeforeAction: ->
      if Session.get("error")
        console.log('error')
      else
        console.log("no error")
```

Then in the console, I change `Session.set("error", true);` and the route is refreshed

Comment: Do you still need help here?

Comment: Yes and no. I figured out the issue. But now I need to find a way to push people to the login page.